# How to handle j2me call events/interruptions

Tags: java-me

I have to implement the code in which **I have to call, then have to get the call duration and also should be notified when the call is ended**.

I know it's **not possible** in j2me with MIDP 2.0 but still if anyone has solved this issue however, plz post ur solutions here. I need it.

I have already done calling with the method **platformRequest()** but I am unable to track the **call duration, event when call was not received and end call event**.

Plz do reply some gud solutions if any of these things is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access this type of native functionality using VM.

You can try and make a rough estimation but this won't cover all circumstances e.g. when you application gets closed or the Date/Time of the phone is changed but it's the best I could think.

You could persist the amount time it has taken using a RecordStore. The basic idea would be to persist the time before you make a call to the platformRequest() and record what the time is within different sections of the MIDlet life cycle functions and make the best guess you can.